# How to write a function that accepts two lists as input and returns their dot product

Tags: python, dot-product

I'm still learning basic of Maya Python script, and it's hard for me to catch up. Actually I don't really understand how dot product works. So it's hard for me to understand what it means by 'function that accepts two lists as input and returns their dot product'. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Then you should research what a dot product is.

Comment: From the [`ìtertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) module's documentation: "For example, the multiplication operator can be mapped across two vectors to form an efficient dot-product: `sum(map(operator.mul, vector1, vector2))`".

Answer (score 1):

```
def dot(l1, l2):
    return sum(x*y for x,y in zip(l1,l2))
```

Or use `numpy`, but the output is a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
result = np.dot(numpy.array(l1), numpy.array(l2))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Actually I don't really understand how dot product works.

Given two vectors `a = (a_1,a_2,...,a_n)` and `b = (b_1,b_2,...,b_n)`, the dot product is the sum `a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 + ... + a_nb_n`.

---

In Python:

```
def dot(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        raise ValueError("a and b have differing sizes")

    sum = 0

    for i in range(len(a)):
        sum += a[i] * b[i]

    return sum
```